# Are arbitrary constants present in a differential equation or a partial differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

ex:$$y=mx+c$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=m$$
$$y=\frac{dy}{dx}.x +c$$
The line equation has 2 arbitrary constants..it implies the DE should be second order...but it isnt and c isnt eliminated too...How do i eliminate c?

Comment: the DE is indeed second order, its $y'' = 0$. The equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = m$ is **not** the DE satisfied by **every** function of the form $mx+c$. This is only true if $m$ is a fixed number, and then yes, its first order

Answer (score 1):

$$y=mx+c\quad\implies\quad \begin{cases}\frac{dy}{dx}=m\\ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0\end{cases}$$
Thus the second order ODE is very simple :
$$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0$$
In solving it you check that the general solution is $\quad y=mx+c\quad$ as expected.